# Get return value from a function called in a Background Job in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

How to get back a return value from a function called as a Background Job?

```
#Create the Status Background Job 
Start-Job -Name "jobGetStatus" -InitializationScript $InitScript -ScriptBlock {$Status = GetStatus}

#Wait for job result
While (Get-Job -Name "jobGetStatus" | where { $_.State -eq "Running" })
    {Start-Sleep 1}

#Get Status on Timer Tick
$Timer.Add_Tick({Get-Job -Name "jobGetStatus" | Receive-Job -Keep})
```

In my case, I call the function "GetStatus" that return an array. The function is contained in the Initialization Script.

Already tried something like this:

```
#Get Status on Timer Tick
$Timer.Add_Tick({$Status = Get-Job -Name "jobGetStatus" | Receive-Job -Keep})
```

This case is killing me....

Comment: `$Status = GetStatus` -> `GetStatus`

Comment: Hi, could you please put it in the sample? The aim is to let the job running and to get the return value on every timer tick.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a timer here? Is it fine for you to get a result when job is done?

```
  $event = Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier NewMessage -Action {
      $global:Status = $event.MessageData
  }

  $scriptBlock =  {
    Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier NewMessage -Forward
    # here is logic for status message #
    $statusMessage = @("Your", "status", "array", "here")
    $null = New-Event -SourceIdentifier NewMessage -MessageData $statusMessage

    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier NewMessage
  }

  Start-Job -Name "jobGetStatus" -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock | out-null

  While (Get-Job -Name "jobGetStatus" | where { $_.State -eq "Running" } )
  {
      Start-Sleep 1
  }

  $global:Status # here you have your status after job is finished

Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
```

Also, don't forget to remove job when you don't need it

Comment: don't ask question on answer, before answer ask all question in comment